# Need to check div visibility to create "navigation menu"

Tags: jquery, html, css, visibility

So, i have this project where images with captions are displayed, when you click a button the next "slide" shows, and the slide that was being shown is hidden. So far so good. My problem is: i need to create a button that checks what div is visible at the moment and hide it and show the div previous that one that has the same class "slide". I also need help with the part where i click the button to show next slide to show the one with same class only, the way i have it it searches for parent elements.

So, the

```
<button class="back"></button>
<div class="slide  active">

    <div class="trapezoid"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67567510/IMG_0296.JPG" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="hover_capt"></div>

    <div class="capt">
      <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
      <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="slide ">

    <div class="trapezoid"><img src="" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="hover_capt"></div>

    <div class="capt">
      <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
      <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="slide ">

    <div class="trapezoid"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67567510/IMG_0296.JPG" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="hover_capt"></div>

    <div class="capt">
      <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
      <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="slide ">

    <div class="trapezoid"><img src="" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="hover_capt"></div>

    <div class="capt">
      <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
      <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide{
  width: 100%;
  height:500px;
  display:none;
}

.centerer{
  width: 100%;
}

.trapezoid { 
  width: 500px;
  height: 333px;  
  background-color: white; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}

.trapezoid img{
  max-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.hover_capt{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  top:-25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.capt{
  text-align:center;
  z-index: -999;
  width:500px;
  background-color:beige;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  top:-50px;
  display:none;
}

/* Center the demo */
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  background-color:#330033;
}

.back{
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  outline: none;
}

.active{
    display:inline;
}
```

And the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".hover_capt" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).parent().find('.capt').slideToggle();
  }
);

$(".hover_capt").click(function(){

  $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().next().addClass('active');

});

$(".back").click(function(){





});



});
```

And finally a [Pen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/YPgNzx)

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".trapezoid").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.capt').slideToggle();
  });

  $(".hover_capt").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().next('.slide').addClass('active');
    if(current.next('.slide').is('.slide:first')) {
      $('.hover_capt').hide();
    }
    $('.back').show(); 
  });

  $(".back").click(function() {
    var current = $('.active');
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.prev('.slide').addClass('active');
    if(current.prev('.slide').is('.slide:first')) {
      $('.back').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

the new query

and updated [Pen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/YPgNzx?editors=011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your jQuery just needs a little clean up and it will be much better.

The searching through parents is fine, but within the `.next()` call, you can specify selectors.

I've also added in the functionality for the back button and changed the call for the slide toggle to be done on the siblings instead of doing a parent call. It cuts out the amount of code required ever so slightly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".hover_capt").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.capt').slideToggle();
  });

  $(".hover_capt").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().next('.slide').addClass('active');
    if($(this).parent().next('.slide').is('.slide:last')) {
      $('.hover_capt').hide();
    }
    $('.back').show(); 
  });

  $(".back").click(function() {
    var current = $('.active');
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.prev('.slide').addClass('active');
    if(current.prev('.slide').is('.slide:first')) {
      $('.back').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
}
.centerer {
  width: 100%;
}
.trapezoid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 333px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.trapezoid img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.hover_capt {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.capt {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -999;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -50px;
  display: none;
}
/* Center the demo */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #330033;
}
.back {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="back"></button>
<div class="slide  active">

  <div class="trapezoid">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67567510/IMG_0296.JPG" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="hover_capt"></div>

  <div class="capt">
    <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
    <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="slide ">

  <div class="trapezoid">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="hover_capt"></div>

  <div class="capt">
    <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
    <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="slide ">

  <div class="trapezoid">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67567510/IMG_0296.JPG" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="hover_capt"></div>

  <div class="capt">
    <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
    <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="slide ">

  <div class="trapezoid">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="hover_capt"></div>

  <div class="capt">
    <p>Tinha 24 Freiras</p>
    <p>Mandei-as Fazer um Doce</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this works as expected

Comment: YES!! just one detail, is it possible so that when it is the first element visible you cant go back any further, or the last element go on further?

Comment: how can i do the same effect for .hover_capt when it's the last slide div?

Comment: if i keep clicking the red button, the .hover_capt, eventually the slide div disapears. the last one should not

Comment: absolutly perfect! kudos!

Comment: ran into a little problem, when i click next and get to the last slide, and then go back, the next button doesnt show and i got no clue how to fix this :/ help?